# Wrong Win 7 distribution installed!

Tags: windows-7

So I just reinstalled Windows 7 on my dad's PC. The thing is i accidently installed Win 7 Ultimate (x64). The key (legit key) I have is for Win 7 Professional (x64).

What are my options. I do have the ISO for Win 7 professional also. Is it just cleaner and safer to reinstall Win 7 professional? how bad is it on the harddrive? the harddrive is fairly new.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Reinstalling will be no problem for your harddrive as you will only be rewriting a small percentage of the disk.

It also seems like the simplest option for you.

Comment: Just make sure you do it before you set everything up, otherwise it's a bother. But since modern HDDs are meant to run with years of use, rewriting a few gigs at the start won't even dent it.